# nearest member in 2 similary griided dataframes with sklearn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

I have 2 dataframes:

df1:

```
                    x             y        c0
2       468958.147443  4.633810e+06  1.253041
43      475516.484948  4.634928e+06  1.423767
72      475802.708042  4.635308e+06  1.294299
106     476658.696529  4.635686e+06  1.338760
133     472671.587615  4.636082e+06  1.325560
              ...           ...       ...
707923  394329.199687  5.006761e+06  1.155477
707980  409697.377813  5.006524e+06  1.223895
708570  411859.618686  5.006875e+06  1.093296
708576  413477.224756  5.006853e+06  1.161713
708695  445559.757010  5.006496e+06  1.149282

[12880 rows x 3 columns]
```

df2:

```
         kat    z0     kr             xx            yy
0        1.0  0.01  0.169  468526.696610  4.633654e+06
1        3.0  0.30  0.214  468757.270633  4.633653e+06
2        1.0  0.01  0.169  468066.930344  4.633965e+06
3        1.0  0.01  0.169  468297.494406  4.633964e+06
4        1.0  0.01  0.169  468528.058460  4.633963e+06
     ...   ...    ...            ...           ...
1287962  3.0  0.30  0.214  399566.653186  5.115395e+06
1287963  3.0  0.30  0.214  399781.023856  5.115391e+06
1287964  1.0  0.01  0.169  396570.675453  5.115753e+06
1287965  1.0  0.01  0.169  396785.035186  5.115750e+06
1287966  1.0  0.01  0.169  399571.712593  5.115703e+06

[1287967 rows x 5 columns]
```

I want to find a nearest member of df1 within certain radius, lets say `radius=500` of df2. Then I want to put this nearest `c0` values to df2. In case there is no df1 point within `radius=500` I want to set `c0` to `1.0` in df2. `(x,y)` and `(xx,yy)` are plane coordinates of df1 and df2, respectively.

Desired output( sample for first 5 rows only ):

```
         kat    z0     kr             xx            yy  c0
0        1.0  0.01  0.169  468526.696610  4.633654e+06  1.253041
1        3.0  0.30  0.214  468757.270633  4.633653e+06  1.253041
2        1.0  0.01  0.169  468066.930344  4.633965e+06  1.0
3        1.0  0.01  0.169  468297.494406  4.633964e+06  1.0
4        1.0  0.01  0.169  468528.058460  4.633963e+06  1.0
     ...   ...    ...            ...           ...
1287962  3.0  0.30  0.214  399566.653186  5.115395e+06  ...
1287963  3.0  0.30  0.214  399781.023856  5.115391e+06  ...
1287964  1.0  0.01  0.169  396570.675453  5.115753e+06  ...
1287965  1.0  0.01  0.169  396785.035186  5.115750e+06  ...
1287966  1.0  0.01  0.169  399571.712593  5.115703e+06  ...
```

I was thinking about converting this into shapefiles and working in some spatial query software. But I believe effective solution can be found here with `sklearn`. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you may use scipy `cKDTree`. It has a reputation of quite fast due to the `C/Cython` implementation. Give it a try to see if it helps you.

I use only first 5 rows from your `df2` for my `df2`. My `df1` is the same as your sample `df1`. I also assume column `c0` is the last column in `df1` and the distance is  `Euclidean`

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

df1_cTree = cKDTree(df1[['x','y']])
ix_arr = df1_cTree.query(df2[['xx','yy']], k=1, distance_upper_bound=500)[1]

df2['c0'] = [df1.iloc[x, -1] if x < len(df1) else 1 for x in ix_arr]

Out[438]:
   kat    z0     kr             xx         yy        c0
0  1.0  0.01  0.169  468526.696610  4633654.0  1.253041
1  3.0  0.30  0.214  468757.270633  4633653.0  1.253041
2  1.0  0.01  0.169  468066.930344  4633965.0  1.000000
3  1.0  0.01  0.169  468297.494406  4633964.0  1.000000
4  1.0  0.01  0.169  468528.058460  4633963.0  1.253041
```

---

**Note**: row index 4 of `df2` has distance from `[468528.058460, 4633963.0]` to row 0 of `df1` `[468958.147443, 4633810]` is `456.4926432`, so it satisfies condition within `500`. Therefore, its `c0` must not `1` as in your desired ouput.